Mapping to DynamicFrame using global variable not working
I have the following DynamicFrame loaded from my S3:
{
    "customerId": "0000907d-07ca-40aa-9bc9-316514b990d1",
    "merchants": [
        "054c7e0d-2093-4a5d-a94d-8688f638b43a",
        "7867425a-5766-4e9d-a580-bc86f29a280f",
        "07f1dfa1-611a-479a-9f42-0ffc3c0e3409",
        "68670b63-17c5-4210-8740-9a70d5190c15",
        "f365bbad-6cac-479f-b8ad-5c5b32d45cef",
        "6b2c1b71-a27c-4d7c-ad53-80745b868a8b",
        "2679c825-7fd9-4713-8a08-9782941b4c93",
        "12351e37-49dd-4216-8981-c8009102690e",
        "36c02eab-a57e-4391-a96e-b769ab1560ee",
        "8f12c85a-10b4-4266-b2a4-c0a6a629ce62"
    ],
    "scores": [
        0.5964582,
        0.0822507,
        0.0327611,
        0.0306084,
        0.024401,
        0.0216996,
        0.0193635,
        0.018442,
        0.0157313,
        0.0133114
    ]
},
{...},...

I need to add to that record more keys, which are accomplished with:
def add_columns(r):
    r["PK"] = "PK#"+r['customerId']
    r["SK"] = "text"
    r["description"] = "text"
    r["type"] = "text"
    r["name"] = "text"

which works just fine.
However, I need to also add information that I have from an dictionary. Example of the my dictionary called mapa_merchants:
[{'merchant_id': 'f65eb540-97d2-4a8a-bd3b-076d3a057661',
  'businessName': 'name1',
  'image': None,
  'url': 'url to store'},
 {'merchant_id': '139155a0-066f-4d8b-bdc5-58eb7ff34850',
  'businessName': 'blabla',
  'image': None,
  'url': 'url2'},
 {'merchant_id': '3ae9190e-dd7b-45fd-8b9e-d3a485c22ed5',
  'businessName': 'blablabla',
  'image': None,
  'url': 'url3'}, ...

I need to gather this dict, filter of the matching ids on the merchants key in the record and add everything to the record, which could be done programmatically with:
def add_columns(r):
    r["PK"] = "PK#"+r['customerId']
    r["SK"] = "text"
    r["description"] = "text"
    r["type"] = "text"
    r["name"] = "text"
    
    #filtering only relevant merchants for that row
    mapa_merchants_user = [dicionario for dicionario in mapa_merchants if dicionario['merchant_id'] in r["merchants"]]
    for dicionario in mapa_merchants_user: #adding the position in the merchants and the scores to the matching map
        indice = r["merchants"].index(dicionario['merchant_id'])
        dicionario['rank'] = indice + 1 #1 indexed
        dicionario['score'] = r['scores'][indice]
    #adding it to the record "item" key
    r["items"] = mapa_merchants_user
    return r

df = df.map(add_columns)

I am expecting it to create a record that looks like this:
pk, sk, etc,
"items": [
  {
   "businessName": "name1",
   "image": "image url",
   "merchantId": "054c7e0d-2093-4a5d-a94d-8688f638b43a",
   "rank": 1,
   "url": "url",
   "score": 0.5964582
  },
  {
   "businessName": "name2",
   "image": "image url",
   "merchantId": "7867425a-5766-4e9d-a580-bc86f29a280f",
   "rank": 2,
   "url": "url",
   "score": 0.0822507
  },

However the result df is simply in blank, no record at all when I try to df.show() it. What am I doing wrong?
